# How do I use requestFocus in a Java JFrame GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, focusmanager

I am given an assignment but I am totally new to Java (I have been programming in C++ and Python for two years).

So we are doing GUI and basically we extended JFrame and added a couple fields.

Say we have a field named "Text 1" and "Text 2". When user presses enter with the cursor in Text 1, move the focus to Text 2. I tried to add

```
private JTextField textfield1() {

    textfield1 = new JTextField();
    textfield1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 20));

    textfield1.addActionListener(
                           new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                            textfield1text = textfield1.getText().trim();
                            textfield1.setText(textfield1text);
                            System.out.println(textfield1text);

                            textfield1.requestFocus();
                        }
                    });

    return textfield1;
}
```

But that doesn't work at all.

I noticed that requestFocus is not recommended, and instead one should use requestFocusWindows. But I tried that too. Upon some readings it seems like I have to do keyboard action and listener? But my teacher said it only requires 1 line...

Comment: If the API says you should use requestFocusInWindow() why would you post code that uses requestFocus(). Follow the recommendation of the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have `textfield1.requestFocus()`, but your description would imply you need `textfield2.requestFocus()`. (that's **2**).

Comment: +1  A good case for meaningful field names.  Also a note to the OP:  It is generally neither necessary nor a good idea to extend top-level containers (JApplet aside).  Instead create the GUI in a JPanel and add it to the TLC (JApplet included).

Answer (score 2):

Another option might be to use:

```
textField1.transferFocus();
```

This way you don't need to know the name of the next component on the form.